# Perl $ENV and $$

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I recently started learning Perl in school and noticed **$ENV** and **$$** in a document.
My teacher told me it's something about process ID's and obviously environment variables, but I still don't fully understand.
Now I am wondering what these two things do and how to use them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$$ http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%ENV

Comment: Is %ENV the same? I have no idea how Perl works.

Comment: you should learn some perl before worrying about either

Answer (score 7):

These are both documented in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$$):

> $$
>   The process number of the Perl running this script.
>
> The hash %ENV contains your current environment

There is no `$ENV` but there might be `$ENV{'PATH'}` which is how you tell to access the 'PATH' from the current environment. The thing that seems to confuse some, is that `%HASH` denotes a whole hash. But an individual value within a hash is a *scalar* and the sigil for scalar is `$`. So you would access `$HASH{'somekey'}`.

Answer (score 2):

both **%ENV** (not **$ENV**) and **$$** are described in [General-Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

- **$$** The process number of the Perl running this script.
- **%ENV** The hash %ENV contains your current environment.